I can't configure SSL with Kafka
I need to connect with Kafka on dev stand
Devops gived me 2 .pfx files for our Kafka.
I create keyStore.jks and trustStore.jks from them with command
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore APD00.00-2208-kafka-d5-client-pdou.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keyStore.jks -deststoretype JKS
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore APD00.00-2208-kafka-d5-client-pdou-truststore.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore trustStore.jks -deststoretype JKS

And configure my application.yaml like this
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: 
      ${SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS:localhost:9092}

producer:
  security:
    protocol: SSL
  ssl:
    key-store-type: JKS
    key-store-location: /app/certs/keyStore.jks
    key-store-password: pass
    trust-store-type: JKS
    trust-store-location: /app/certs/trustStore.jks
    trust-store-password: pass

But I get an Exception
[dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer] with root cause

java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
at java.base/sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:294) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:162) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetKey(KeyStoreDelegator.java:93) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1075) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init>(SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:141) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
at java.base/javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:270) ~[na:na]

If I create keystore with key
keytool -genkeypair -alias doul-key -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 365 -keystore keyStore.jks -storetype JKS

and
key-store-key: doul-key
key-password: pass

Then I get
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: SSL private key can be specified only for PEM, but key store type is JKS.

What am I doing wrong?
